# Fast screen sharing

Tags: network, wifi, airport, mac-mini, server.app

Ok, so, I want to buy a Mac Mini with OS X server. I want to run it without any monitor, or keyboards, or mouse. Now, I want to control it remotely from my MacBook via Screen Sharing. Since I have another MacBook in the family, I tested Screen Sharing to see if it works well. When I tested this on my house's current network configuration (A single router, and the two MacBooks connected to this router), I noticed the screen sharing was  kind of slow. So I created a peer to peer network between the two computers, and tested screen sharing again. Using the peer to peer network, it runs a lot faster. So, is it possible to kind of directly and wirelessly connect my MacBook and the Mac Mini, and connect to the Wi-Fi internet at the same time, or something that would make screen sharing faster? (Also notice I can't connect the Mac Mini to the internet via ethernet in my bedroom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so now I have the Mac Mini as a server, and I tried to configure the network in the way I wanted to. From my google searches I've found that the Mac mini can't connect to a Wi-Fi router and be a Wireless router at the same time. But I have a good solution... I have my Mac mini connected to the Wireless router, and I bought an Ethernet cable, that I eventually use to connect my MacBook directly to the Mac Mini for faster screen sharing. Using this direct connection through the Ethernet cable makes screen sharing pretty fast... I mean, it's NOT 100% perfect, but you can control the computer quite smoothly if you are using the "Adaptive quality" configuration found in the menu bar of the screen sharing app.